# Convert List<Map<String, Comparable<>>> to List<Map<String, Object>>

Tags: java, type-conversion

I am using a method that return me a `List<Map<String, Comparable<?>>>`
and I would like to convert the result using a stream() and end up with a `List<Map<String, Object>>`.

My code is similar to the following:

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> myMethod() {
    List<Map<String, Comparable<?>>> result = anotherMethod();
    return ?
}
```

How can I convert the list `result` using a `stream()` in order to return a `List<Map<String, Object>>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casting of the maps' values to `Object` should work:

```java
public List<Map<String, Object>> myMethod() {
    return anotherMethod().stream()
        .map(m -> m.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey, e -> (Object)e.getValue()
                ))
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Indeed. Don't know how I didn't think about this :/ Thank you !